# How to send or play midi from one application to another

Tags: midi, daw, signal-routing

How do I send or play midi from one application to another?

Example:

1. Import a midi file into the DAW software.
2. The DAW plays the imported midi data sending it to some midi receiver, for example, a DJ software, Traktor pro.
3. The midi data only consists of control change messages, i.e. no note message is included.

So how could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your other MIDI receiver is hardware or software running on another machine, you simply route the midi track to a midi output (granted that your interface has a MIDI out port).

On the other hand, if you need to route the output to some other software on the same machine, you need some virtual MIDI port (or "loop back") software. One solution is loopMIDI:

http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html

If you're on a mac, creating a virtual port might be the answer:

http://www.johanlooijenga.com/tools/5-apps/12-virtual-ports.html

Comment: thank you very much. For my case, your answer suggests I need loopMIDI.